# Non-interactive android application

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

I am working on an Android application for plug PC (which will be connected to TVs) that requires no user interaction. The content being presented on the screen is periodically fetched from server. The fetched data is being processed and presented onto the UI  using long running Async-task. There is only one activity that displays images, videos and pdfs.

Although app is running fine, but long running async tasks is not a good design decision and definitely not scalable. How do I design an application that has no UI, need processing before data is being displayed onto UI ?

Comment: Pretty sure you want to use a Service or IntentService  for long running operations. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: I need to frequently update UI, can't do that outside if main thread. How to resolve this ?

Comment: Then I guess you could use a Handler. https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html